# Prevent duplicate python processes

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have a script that has the code like this

```
import time

def myFunction():
    // Do something in background by using Process()

print("Running the first time")
myFunction()

print("Running the second time (and wait 3 seconds)")
myFunction()

time.sleep(3)

print("Running the last time")
myFunction()

time.sleep(3)
```

I want to prevent duplicate processing. So the output should be like this

```
Running the first time
[myFunction] Working on something! This will take about 2 seconds to finish the process
Running the second time (and wait 3 seconds)
[myFunction] Sorry! the latest process is still working
[myFunction] Process done!
Running the last time
[myFunction] Working on something! This will take about 2 seconds to finish the process
[myFunction] Process done!
```

Is there a way to make a function like this in Python?

Comment: why does it need to be concurrent? when it is being run in order? lol i'm confused.

Comment: You can `.join()` the previous process before launching a new one.